# C#: How can I save a portion of the Command Screen for later use?

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-interface

I'm learning how to code C# from scratch. Right now, I'm learning how to build a scene on the command line and update it as necessary.

Part of what i want to do is to "scroll text as it is generated".

The scene is a square command line (Size 100 by 40) and outlined by a box of "#" characters. This is the canvas on which everything is presented.

As the user interacts via simple inputs, the program will provide textual feedback, like a text-based game.

However, unlike a normal text-based game, I cannot allow for the natural flow of the command line to move the canvas. In other words, if I allow for the command line to act naturally, then the canvas would slowly travel upwards until it's no longer visible.

I need a way to read whatever is already being presented on the screen and storing it on memory. Then, I can delete a portion of the screen an paste the previously copied information shifted upwards, making space for new information.

Here is a mockup of what I want to do:

[Image 1: desirable outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9DvQ.png)

My question is: Is there a way to "read" only a specific portion of the command space and store into memory?

I know you can store whatever is being printed at the moment of printing, or I could keep track of a certain number of previously displayed information and print it again, but I would like to "copy, then paste shifted" a portion of the screen.

PS: This is what I'm trying to avoid
[Image 2: Undesirable outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgDa7.png)

Comment: You have no need to know what is on the screen. Just clear it and write it. You can keep track of what has been written and what needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Since the top line needs to be moved too, really the only way to do this is to clear the screen and redraw everything. Instead of printing directly to the screen, save the new line to a list, clear the screen, then print that list to the screen, together with the border.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't found a way to store a portion of the command line to a variable for later use, I've succesfully "scrolled" the text, and found a workaround to "store" it.

Simply put, Console.MoveBufferArea() allows one to select a portion of the command line buffer and move it somewhere else on the buffer.

This way I can:

-Clear whatever space i need at the top by moving the cursor to, say, (1,1) and writing a box of spaces via a string.

-Console.MoveBofferArea() the portion of the buffer a few rows upwards

-Write the new text at the bottom

As a byproduct, i can also "store" a portion of the screen for late use by:

-Setting the buffer to a wider area with Console.SetBufferSize()

-Use Console.MoveBufferArea() to the buffer portion that is outside of normal view

-Do whatever i need to do on the screen

-Use Console.MoveBufferArea() to retrieve the "stored" portion back to where i need it

-Reduce the buffer area (I could also just leave it be)